# Force a Datatype importing from Excel to DataGrid

Tags: excel, vb.net, import, dataset

As many people do, I use the OleDb methond to import from an Excel file to a dataset, and then display it in a DataGrid:

```
Dim sqlExcel As String = "SELECT [codPropioPersona], [Nombres], [ApPaterno], [ApMaterno], [CI], [Sexo], [Direccion], [Telefonos], [PorcDescuento] FROM [hoja1$]"
Dim oledbConn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(sConnectionString)
            oledbConn.Open()
            Dim oledbCmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sqlExcel, oledbConn)
            Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(oledbCmd)

            DS = New DataSet()
  da.Fill(DS)`
```

BUT, it happens that [CI] is an text column in Excel, but whe it Fills de DS, it comes as DOUBLE...! so, some CIs comes fine (if they are numbers), but when it's Aplhanum, the field shows as EMPTY (it doesn't keep the datatype from excel so, it avoids it).

I have tried using Cast(CI as varchar) in the SQL, but in Oledb-Excel it doesn't work.. So, how can I really force to recognize [CI] as varchar-string, and not as DOUBLE??
thanks!

Comment: https://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/treating-data-as-text/

Comment: Thanks, it works, BUT this number in excel: 7052130, is read as 7.05213e+006. Please, how can I keep it as 7052130?

Comment: That's the same number though?  It's difficult to tell exactly what the problem is since you don't mention how you're viewing this value on the vb.net side.  Is it possible that the scientific notation is just an auto-applied formatting?

Comment: I display the result in a DataGridView (so the user can check it's excel prior to final import), BUT even in the DataSet (linked later to DataGridView), it's in scientific notation...

Comment: What is the value's Type ?  Is it actually text?

Comment: Yes, it is text all the column

Comment: Sorry I don't have any other suggestions, except to check each value parse it to a number if it's numeric.